# tkinter fails to display my .png button image

Tags: python, image, tkinter

The following program attempts to display a row of four buttons. The inner two, "ArrowLeft" and "ArrowRight", display correctly. The outer two do not show the image. I have tried two different strategies in this code for importing the image ("LeftLeft" and "RightRight") and by no means will it work. Since I can't attach the image files in their original form, here is a zip file that includes the code below and six very small .png files. If anyone could take a look and see what is going wrong, I would sure appreciate it.

The alternative tryCanvas code successfully displays the LeftLeft image!

Zip file:  https://easyupload.io/ubnfn1

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, PhotoImage
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

def layout(frame):
    global leftIcon, upIcon, rightIcon, downIcon
    leftLeft1 = Image.open("LeftLeft.png")
    leftLeft1.show()
    leftIcon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "ArrowLeft.png")
    leftLeftIcon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(leftLeft1)
    rightIcon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="ArrowRight.png")
    rightRightIcon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "RightRight.png")
    ttk.Button(frame, image=leftLeftIcon).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    ttk.Button(frame, image=leftIcon).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    ttk.Button(frame, image=rightIcon).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    ttk.Button(frame, image=rightRightIcon).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

def tryCanvas():
    can1 = tk.Canvas(root)
    image = PhotoImage(file='LeftLeft.png')
    item = can1.create_image(100, 100, image = image)
    can1.image = image
    can1.pack()

# tryCanvas()
layout(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: It is because the variables (`leftIcon` and `rightIcon`) for the images of the inner two buttons are declared as global variables, but those variables (`leftLeftIcon` and `rightRightIcon`) are just local variables.  So the later two will be garbage collected after the function exits.

Comment: Oh for crying out loud! Makes perfect sense, once you understand this really odd quirk of tkinter and its memory management. Ouch!

But does anyone understand why this wart on the side of Python memory management is allowed to persist? Why tkinter (or its Python interface) doesn't practice the normal discipline of incrementing the reference count when it takes a PhotoImage under its wing?